# css label для блока

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как сделать такой эффект [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть существует квадратный блок, и ему надо сделать продолжение, словно он оборачивает блок. Понять не могу с чего начать. Подскажите, кто может

```css
   .site_users_rating::before {
    content: ' ';
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid green;
    border-bottom: 20px solid green;
   }
   .site_users_rating {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="rating">
   <div class="site_users_rating">3</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Квадратный блок выступает за край, а треугольничек сделать с помощью псевдоэлемента =)

Comment: щас попробую)))

Comment: @ДанилЧугаев залил код, всяко пробовал его подвинуть как надо, не получается чего-то

Comment: а все я нашел косяк, оказывается, родительскому элементу надо ставить position: relative, хотя я думал он по умолчанию стоит, если не выбираешь

Comment: У `position` значение по умолчанию `static` =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.site_users_rating::before {
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  right: 26px; top: 0px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid green;
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
  z-index: -1;
}
.site_users_rating {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="rating">
   <div class="site_users_rating">5</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типа этого

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.text-block{
  position:relative;
  margin:20px;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  width:150px;
}
.text-block__label{
  position:absolute;
  top:-15px;
  left:25px;
  background-color:#0f0;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px 5px;
  writing-mode:tb-rl;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  box-shadow:-2px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.text-block__label:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:100%;
  border-bottom:15px solid #265026;
  border-left:10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-block">
  <span>asdasd asdas da das das dasd a sdas dadasd asdadasd asa dasd a sdasd asd ad asd asd asd asd a</span>
  <div class="text-block__label">Label</div>
</div>
```